# Árboles binarios - [Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando eliminar un nodo en *Arboles Binarios*, sin embargo tengo el error mencionado en mi función para reemplazar, donde se le asigna nuevos hijos o padre.

```cpp
//PARA REEMPLAZAR NODOS
void ArbolBB::reemplazar(NodoArbolB *apuntadorNodo,NodoArbolB *apuntadorNuevoNodo){
    
    if(apuntadorNodo->getPadre()){//HAY QUE ASIGNARLE SU NUEVO HIJO
        
        if(apuntadorNodo->getValor() == apuntadorNodo->getPadre()->getIzquierda()->getValor()){
            apuntadorNodo->getPadre()->getIzquierda() = apuntadorNuevoNodo;//AQUI ME DA EL ERROR
        
        }else if(apuntadorNodo->getValor() == apuntadorNodo->getPadre()->getDerecha()->getValor()){
            apuntadorNodo->getPadre()->getDerecha() = apuntadorNuevoNodo;//AQUI TAMBIEN
        
        }
    }
    if(apuntadorNuevoNodo){//SE ASIGNA SU NUEVO PADRE
        apuntadorNuevoNodo->getPadre() = apuntadorNodo->getPadre();//Y AQUI
    }
    
}
```

```
239 46  

C:\Users\rdjr\Documents\UV\3Semestre\EstructuraDeDatos\Actividades\ProyectoArbolesDeBusqueda\ArbolBB.cpp
[Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Comment: ¿ Cual es el prototipo de `getIzquierda( )` y `getDerecha( )` ? ¿ Que devuelven esas funciones ?

Comment: El error es muy claro, lo que retorna esto: `apuntadorNodo->getPadre()->getIzquierda()` no es una variable que puedas usar en una asignación (lvalue) y asignarle la dirección de memoria de `apuntadorNuevoNodo`, que es lo que pretendes en esa línea.

Comment: Esto devuelve mis gettters. `int NodoArbolB::getValor(){
    return valor;
}
void NodoArbolB::setValor(int valor){
    this->valor = valor;
}
NodoArbolB* NodoArbolB::getDerecha(){
    return derecha;
}
void NodoArbolB::setDerecha(NodoArbolB* derecha){
    this->derecha = derecha;
}
NodoArbolB* NodoArbolB::getIzquierda(){
    return izquierda;
}
void NodoArbolB::setIzquierda(NodoArbolB* izquierda){
    this->izquierda = izquierda;
}


NodoArbolB* NodoArbolB::getPadre(){
    return padre;
}
void NodoArbolB::setPadre(NodoArbolB* padre){
    this->padre = padre;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, el error:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Ese mensaje te está indicando que estás intentando asignar un valor a algo a lo que no es posible asignarle dicho valor.

#### ¿¡¿¡ *Meloxplique* !?!?

Pasa que **no todo** admite estar **a la izquierda** de un operador de asignación `=`.

- Literales:

  ```
  5 = hola; // ERROR !
  ```
- Constantes (después de la asignación inicial):

  ```
  const int A = 10;
  ...
  A = 15; // ERROR !
  ```
- **Elementos temporales** (es tu caso):

  ```
  int algo( ) { return 5; }

  algo( ) = 4; // ERROR !
  ```

  Es una medida de seguridad. Asignar algo a un temporal es **completamente inútil**, puesto que el temporal dejará de existir **justo al terminar la asignación**.

  Aquí cada uno puede tener la opinión que mas le apetezca: puede que sea una instancia de una clase nuestra, y el `operator=( )` tenga *efectos colaterales* independientes de la instancia ... vale, maravilloso. Pero el lenguaje estipula que asignar a un temporal es incorrecto, y no hay mas que hablar.

  Esto **no pasa** si devuelves referencias; una referencia no es *la cosa*, es *una forma de acceder a la cosa*:

  ```
  int &algo( ) {
    static int Value = 10;

    return Value;
  }

  algo( ) = 0; // CORRECTO !
  ```

#### ¡ Pero si yo estoy devolviendo un puntero !

Pasa que, desde el punto de vista del lenguaje, un puntero **es un tipo completo**, con las mismas *propiedades* que el tipo *al que apunta*. Es decir, un puntero **es una cosa**, no *una forma de acceder a la cosa*.

#### Vale vale. Maravilloso. Muy chulo y eso, pero ... ¿ Como lo arreglo ?

Pues, en tu caso, y a falta de mas datos, bastaría con que tus funciones problemáticas devolvieran *referencias*:

```
NodoArbolB *&NodoArbolB::getDerecha( ) {
    return derecha;
}

NodoArbolB *&NodoArbolB::getIzquierda( ) {
    return izquierda;
}
```